# i am trying to get some info from unsplash using unsplash api but i am getting an error, can someone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native, axios

```
import React from "react"
import {Text, View, Button, Animated, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Alert} from "react-native"
import axios from "axios"

var { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window") ;

export default class App extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount() {

     axios.get("https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/?client_id=80e448841ff2a298408c349608b93aeafe65840c8266061e2c98f1ba3dc60456&query=flower")
       .then(res=>  Alert.alert(res.data)).catch(error=> console.log("erorr present"))        
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View style = {styles.container}><Text>Hello</Text></View>
    )
  }               
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: What error are you hitting?

Comment: the one I have written inside the catch block

Comment: i checked the link on browser too and it is showing me the data but here using axios i am not able to get it

Comment: i mean can you do `.catch(error=> console.log("erorr present", error))` and tell what does this logs?

Comment: erorr present [Error: Network Error], this is what i am getting

Comment: That's a network error. Check your internet and try again

Comment: so brother I solved the problem. I just had to turn my private firewall off and it started working.thank you for the help